# API call in Android 9 configuration devices and emulator shows connection error

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie, network-connection

I am using Android 9 emulator, it has internet connection from system and I have added internet permission in manifest. When I try to call api it shows error message as : **connection error**.

Comment: `api it shows connection error.` What error?

Comment: please show error message

Comment: I am using AndroidNetworking for api calling. it only shows "connection error"

Comment: There might be different connection error. Like `Internet connection` ,`Server Connection` error. What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to 115.124.98.77 not permitted

Comment: _Starting with Android 9.0 (API level 28), cleartext support is disabled by default_. So you need to add  `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`
in manifest file with in `application` flag. By default it will be `false`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Piyush commented in my question the answer is to add
`android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in **manifest** file with in `application` tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.mypackage">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/appicon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        //your android components...
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add below in **manifest's application** tag

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

Add below code inside the `<application>` where we add `activities`

```
 <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
```

Add the XML folder in the res folder. and create a `network_security_config.xml` file in the XML folder.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <network-security-config>
        <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
            <domain includeSubdomains="true">your domain which is your base url for webservice.com</domain>
        </domain-config>
    </network-security-config>
```