# Android 9 (Pie) - Not able to capture any api (native / web) through network monitoring tools such Charles proxy and Fiddler

Tags: android, fiddler, charles-proxy, android-9.0-pie

I am trying to capture apis triggered from native app and website through Charles proxy / Fiddler , But I am not able to see any api there.

I have set manual proxy as well.

I am able to see apis for Android 8 and below . But not working for Android 9 .

In Android 9 , I could the screens getting loaded completely , but still I am not able to see the apis in any monitor.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53368470/emulator-with-android-9-configuration-shows-connection-error

Comment: @Athira , Its not working . I am not seeing the apis after implementing the properties and network_security_config.xml file.

Comment: in AndroidManifest.xml add

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get charles proxy work with Android 7 nougat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39215229/how-to-get-charles-proxy-work-with-android-7-nougat). Especially check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39227880/150978

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="your pckag">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
</manifest>
```

Comment: android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" this is the line

Comment: I have done , but still not working .Issue is network transaction is happening but it is bypassing the proxy tool in Android 9.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:supportsRtl="true" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>        
</application>

Comment: You can't make it work by simply editing the AndroidManifest.xml. You have to add a 
Network security configuration instead.