# webview permissions android pie

Tags: android, webview, socket.io

I have an app that runs a `HTML` page inside a `webview` that connects via the `socket.io` library to a `nodejs` server running a `socket.io` server. When I run the app in a simulator in my PC, the app connects perfectly every time, but when I run it on my Samsung Galaxy S9 Plus it won't connect. When I open the HTML page from my phone's browser it also connects perfectly. The only thing that is different on my phone and the simulator is the Android version. The simulator is running Android Oreo, and my phone is running Android Pie.

The question is: is there any change in webview settings/permissions since Android Pie that may cause this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54451203/android-9-pie-not-able-to-capture-any-api-native-web-through-network-mon/54456657#54456657

Answer (score 2):

In your application tag inside manifest write below line

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

See for reference-
https://koz.io/android-m-and-the-war-on-cleartext-traffic/

Comment: I tried, but i can't because i have < 15 reputation :(

Comment: Just curious, it says: If not declared, the default value is TRUE. All apps behave as before: there are no default restrictions in using HTTP.

Why does declaring it fix my problem?

Comment: In android P it's default value is false dude.

Answer (score 1):

You can use;

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```